# Relacionamento Through Many-To-Many ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relacionamento, active-record, rails4

Tenho a seguinte configuração no rails:

**Company**

```
 has_many :company_products
 has_many :products, :through => :company_products
```

**Product**

```
 has_many :company_products
 has_many :companies, :through => :company_products
```

**ProductGroup**

```
 has_many :company_products
```

**CompanyProduct**

```
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :product_group
```

---

Preciso validar sempre que criar o `Company` ou `Product` se contém um `CompanyProduct` também.

Como posso realizar a validação do `CompanyProduct` pelo Company ou `Product` ?

Answer (score 0):

Em um relacionamento `has_many throught` você pode utilizar o `uniq` para garantir que não serão criados relacionamentos duplicados. Ficaria algo como:

**Company**

```
 has_many :company_products
 has_many :products, -> { uniq }, :through => :company_products
```

**Product**

```
 has_many :company_products
 has_many :companies, -> { uniq }, :through => :company_products
```

**ProductGroup**

```
 has_many :company_products
```

**CompanyProduct**

```
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :product_group
```